# Добавить HTML в каждый блок JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет! Как на JS или jQuery добавить HTML код в каждый блок слайдера, чтобы он был до внутреннего блока inner?
Вот пример блоков:

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Что надо сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я всё правильно понимаю

```js
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".block");

[...blocks].forEach((elem, index) => {

  // Любые манипуляции с HTML кодом. Например, здесь я
  // создал для каждого блока свой спан с текстом и 
  // вставил как первый дочерний элемент

  const span = document.createElement("span");
  span.textContent = `this is ${index + 1} span`;
  
  elem.prepend(span);
});
```

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо!